# is there any solution related to this error?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing

```
(B, G, R) = cv2.split(img)
  IB = equalization_bihistogram(B)
  IG = equalization_bihistogram(G)
  IR = equalization_bihistogram(R)
  IN = np.concatenate((IB, IG, IR))
  plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
  plt.title("A).Histogram Equalization")
  plt.imshow(img)
  plt.show()
  plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
  plt.title("B).Bi-histogram Equalization")
  plt.imshow(cv2.normalize(IN), cmap='gray')
  plt.show()
```

error is:-TypeError: normalize() missing required argument 'dst' (pos 2) i try to set the second parameter as a "None" in cv2.normalize function but this is not work.